# How can I install kernel 3.4 and its sources on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

The application I am trying to build is incompatible with the current kernel (3.19). It only supports kernel versions up to 3.4. I'm running ubuntu 14.04.

What would be the correct procedure to install 3.4 and its sources on my system (I'm running it in a virtual machine if that makes any difference).

I was thinking of grabbing the kernel from here:
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4-precise/

Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

The procedure is similar for at least every Linux kernel, just look at the documentation: [Build kernel on Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel)

The official kernel sources are here: [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/)